# Why I must have Map<Long,... and not Map<long,

Tags: java

That's all. I understand that Long is an object, and long is a primitve type, so why can't I map an object to a number?

Comment: It's because Generics in Java don't (yet!) work with primitives.

Comment: The only thing you must: read about how stack overflow works; and that people expect you to do prior research.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... `Long` is not an object, it is a `Class`.

Now about your question...

In Generics,unlike C#, Java doesn't support primitive type yet.